# What is the difference between force_tz() and with_tz() in the lubridate package of R?

Tags: r, r-package

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between with_tz() and force_tz() in the lubridate package of R? As I was coding I got the same result when using either so I got confused in what circumstances should I use with_tz() over force_tz(), and vice versa.

```
meeting <- ymd_hms("1998-08-28 09:00:00", tz= "Asia/Kathmandu")

mistake1<- with_tz(meeting, "America/ Chicago")
with_tz(a, "Asia/Kathmandu")

mistake2 <- force_tz(meeting, "America/Chicago")
with_tz(mistake,"Asia/Kathmandu")


mistake3 <- force_tz(meeting, "America/Chicago")
force_tz(mistake,"Asia/Kathmandu")
```

Comment: The functions documentation seems to describe clearly the difference: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/force_tz.html, https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/with_tz.html

Answer (score 1):

So following from the documentation the key difference is that:

> `with_tz` returns a date-time as it would appear in a different time zone. **The actual moment of time measured does not change, just the time zone it is measured in.**

whereas the other function

> `force_tz` returns the date-time **that has the same clock time as input time, but in the new time zone.**

So, in other words, one function encodes a time point in a different time zone whereas the other function only changes the time zone designation. This is actually a crucial distinction as if you consider a time line, `with_tz` will make a reference to the same point in the time line. The `force_tz` enables you to change the time zone of the time stamp.

This actually shows how well designed is the `lubridate` package. Consider a scenario where you may be willing to conduct analysis where you may be able to say something about events taking place in the evening across multiple localities. In that context you may be willing to *preserve the timepoints.* Depending on the details it may make sense to recode the timestamps so those are within the same time zone and you can select events taking placer after 8pm.

In an alternative scenario you may be willing to look at events that took place within 18 hours from an arbitrary time point across multiple localities. You would need to bring those events into a common time zone so you can show the span of hours. In that context the actual hour of event is not relevant (whether it was evening or morning) but whether the event took place within 18 hours from point X (say point X is afternoon GMT). You want for the reset of events to be on the GMT scale.

```
library("lubridate")
x <- ymd_hms("2009-08-07 00:00:01", tz = "America/New_York")

with_tz(x, "GMT")
# [1] "2009-08-07 04:00:01 GMT"
force_tz(x, "GMT")
# [1] "2009-08-07 00:00:01 GMT"

with_tz(x, "America/Costa_Rica")
# "2009-08-06 22:00:01 CST"
force_tz(x, "America/Costa_Rica")
# "2009-08-07 00:00:01 CST"
```