# lubridate with_tz unexpected behavior with CEST and UTC

Tags: r, datetime

I observed the following unexpected behavior of `lubridate`s `with_tz`:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# any example time
time = as.POSIXct("2016-08-01 10:00:00 UTC",tz = 'UTC')

# check:
tz(time)
#> [1] "UTC"
print(time)
#> [1] "2016-08-01 10:00:00 UTC"

with_tz(time,tz = 'CEST')
#> [1] "2016-08-01 10:00:00 CEST"
with_tz(time,tz = 'UCT')
#> [1] "2016-08-01 10:00:00 UTC"
with_tz(time,tz = 'America/New_York')
#> [1] "2016-08-01 06:00:00 EDT"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

How is it possible that using `with_tz()` with `tz = 'CEST'` or `tz = 'UTC'` both returns 2016-08-01 10:00:00, even though there is a 2-hour difference between the two timezones? As the last example shows, the printed time changes when we use `tz = 'America/New_York'`.

This behavior seems inconsistent with the description of `with_tz`:
*with_tz returns a date-time as it would appear in a different time zone. The actual moment of time measured does not change, just the time zone it is measured in. with_tz defaults to the Universal Coordinated time zone (UTC) when an unrecognized time zone is inputted. See Sys.timezone() for more information on how R recognizes time zones.*

The problem can be avoided by using `force_tz()` instead, but I'd like to understand whether this behavior of `with_tz()` is intended or a bug? In addition, if I use `force_tz()` I obtain:

```
force_tz(time, tz = 'CEST')
"2016-08-01 08:00:00 CEST"
```

This behavior seems at odds with the description and examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449980/what-is-the-difference-between-force-tz-and-with-tz-in-the-lubridate-package) and in the description of `lubridate::with_tz`?

Comment: Is `tz="UCT"` intentional or a typo?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `lubridate` package, since `attr(time, 'tzone') <- 'CEST'` still results in `"2016-08-01 10:00:00 CEST"`.

Comment: @r2evans No, sorry, it was not, but this does actually not affect behaviour

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong to question the results, I'm saying that identifying it as a problem with or unique to `lubridate` is not correct. It occurs with base R, so the [tag:lubridate] tag is misleading.

Comment: try with `tz = 'CET'`,  this is what `OlsonNames()` lists for me. It should handle (and indicate) daylight saving for you depending on the actual date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by user margusl, one should use `with_tz(time,tz = 'CET')` rather than `with_tz(time,tz = 'CEST')`, even for times falling in Central European Summer Time:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
time = as.POSIXct("2016-08-01 10:00:00 UTC",tz = 'UTC')
with_tz(time,tz = 'CET')
#> [1] "2016-08-01 12:00:00 CEST"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A list of timezone-strings recognized by `R` can be obtained from `OlsonNames()`