Daylight saving overlap, when casting strings to POSIX in R
I have a file of datetime strings which I read in, with the added information, if it is daylight saving time or not, so for example the format:
"2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"

But this time datetime value can also exist as
"2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET"

depending on the fact if the time was measured before or after the time switch.
If I have a string like this, I want to parse it into a POSIXct object, but so that it keeps the info of CEST or CET. If I parse this string into POSIXct, the result is
> as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:30 CEST", tz="Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:30 CET", tz="Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"

This means I lose the information about CET.
Is there a possibility to parse the string into POSIXct and keep the information, which also works for different timezones?
The only possibility I found so far is using
> as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:30 CET", tz="Europe/Berlin")+60*60
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET"

to switch the time back again to CET, but this solution is hardly generalizable for all timezones, since I would have to know, when the switch happends for each timezone, and which substring (e.g. CEST and CET) stands for before and after the time switch and then to decide if I want to add the hour or not.
Would greatly appreaciate any help.

Is it an option to check if the string contains CEST or CET and store this information in a separate column?

I dont think that you can specify the timezone "CEST"/ "CET"  in x. I cant fully understand the doc:,  " If a time zone is needed and that specified is invalid on your system, what happens is system-specific but attempts to set it will probably be ignored. " : but random letters (Ex "abc)    as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 01:30 abc", tz="Europe/Berlin") give the sames results.


Also, take note that "CEST" is not a valid input , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181154/13203906.
I am not sure if you made a typo in your first example: <<But this time datetime value can also exist as "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET" >> Did you try to highlight setting the hour back for winter time and so should be read "1:30" ?
3- Are you expecting to know the tz (the city) ? Can you expect that  the time will be expressed in a coherent manner  with the Daylight saving time period?


@WojciechArtichowicz In principle yes, but since the approach has to work with different timezones I would have to know prior which of both versions is the daylight saving time version and which not (if it even exists for the time zone). If no other option is possible I have to rewrite the files and instead of CEST or CET (or the alternatives in other TZ) to add a flag that indicates if it is daylight saving or not, then to parse first to POSIXlt, set the flags, under $isdst and parse again to POSIXct, but this would be not a preferred solution, since I would prefer not to alter the files.

@VinceGreg
2. In R it is recreatable with:

t = as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:30:00")
t
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"
t+60*60
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET"
The system which creates the files will create entries in the hour before the DST (Daylight saving time) switch and after, without a possibility to specify if DST or not was in place at the time, the date becomes ambigous in R, which will create problems down the line.


I know from the read in file the timezone in the form of "Europe/Berlin", "America/New_York" or etc. and that the endings, eg. CET will correspond to the TZ.



As a non-europen, it took me a while to understand that you are exactly on the end of the daylight time.  "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET" happen one hour after "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST" .
Be aware that your locale affect your output.  as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:30:00") give me "2024-10-27 02:30:00 EDT" on my Eastern Canada machine.


I think the answer to this question is you cannot. This is due to
> "CEST" %in% OlsonNames()
[1] FALSE
> "CET" %in% OlsonNames()
[1] TRUE

Either coming to terms with
> d = c("2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET", "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST")
> as.POSIXct(d, tz="Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST" "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"

or extract the "extra info" with
> data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(d, tz="Europe/Berlin"), 
+            add = gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", d))
                 date  add
1 2024-10-27 02:30:00  CET
2 2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST

as mentioned by user @Wojciech Artichowicz in the comments.

The only way (I can think of) to consistently get the right "Summer/Wintertime branded Time Zone" (CET/CEST) around the summer- to wintertime switch is a lookup table consisting of both overlapping times, where you compare your character input with the table.
Function and table
getDTZ <- \(lookup, charDate) 
  lookup[format.POSIXct(lookup, "%F %T %Z") == charDate]

lookupTable <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 02:00:00"),
                          as.POSIXct("2024-10-27 03:00:00"), 1)

output
getDTZ(lookupTable, "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST")
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CEST"

getDTZ(lookupTable, "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET")
[1] "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET"

class(getDTZ(lookupTable, "2024-10-27 02:30:00 CET"))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

In production, you can check if you have a savings date/time and around that hour use the function.
